# What does “make something stick” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

There was the following passage in New York Times (April 13) article titled, “Philosophy returns to the real world”:

> “It was in one of Fish’s seminars that I first read
>   arch-postmodernist, Richard Rorty, He convincingly defended himself
>   against the charge of relativism – I know, having spent hours in his
>   office, trying to **make it stick** — and yet he maintained that it was
>   useless to talk about the world, or truth. It was impossible, he
>   asserted, to try to describe reality outside of our linguistic
>   practices, to describe it as it would be if it were not being
>   described.”

What does “make it stick” mean here? Does it mean “correct,” “change one’s mind” or “fix the other’s mind rightly”? Is it a popular idiom?

I was unable to get an answer by Googling it.

Comment: Link, please. Always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching Yahoo for

**"make something stick" meaning**

is one of the basic and good ways to find the meaning of a word. You don't seem to have used it, otherwise you'd have found

> **make something stick** to cause something to be accepted or agreed to
>
> *Investigators didn't have the evidence to make the charges stick.*
>
> *Workers got a good agreement and made it stick by threatening another costly strike.*
>
> http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+stick

The narrator seems to have tried to make Rorty recognize that he (Rorty) was indeed a relativist, to make him accept the accusation/charge of relativism, to accept he was "guilty" of it.

Now, relativism is:

> Relativism is the concept that points of view have no absolute truth
>   or validity, having only relative, subjective value according to
>   differences in perception and consideration.[1](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativism) As moral relativism,
>   the term is often used in the context of moral principles, where
>   principles and ethics are regarded as applicable in only limited
>   context. There are many forms of relativism which vary in their degree
>   of controversy.[2] The term often refers to truth relativism, which is
>   the **doctrine that there are no absolute truths**, i.e., that truth is
>   always relative to some particular frame of reference, such as a
>   language or a culture (cultural relativism).
>
> **[Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativism)**

Answer (score 1):

[Make stick](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+stick):

> - to cause something to be accepted or agreed to. *Investigators didn't have the evidence to make the charges stick. Workers got a good agreement and made it stick by threatening another costly strike.* (Cambridge Dict.)

The Free Dictionary

Comment: You should paraphrase the substance of what is said at your link should be provided, in case the site linked disappears or changes its address.